Problem with Error.captureStackTrace(err, this);
I am trying to send a transaction using Jupiter's API and I keep getting this error.  Anybody has some idea for me to make it work?
CODE :
const rawTransaction = transaction.serialize()
const txid = await sendAndConfirmRawTransaction(connection, rawTransaction, {
  skipPreflight: true,
  maxRetries: 2
});

ERROR :
Error.captureStackTrace(err, this);
            ^

TypeError: fetch failed
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:12502:13
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async ClientBrowser.callServer (/Users/louisroylangevin/Desktop/Programmation/Jupiter/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:4997:17) {
  [cause]: [Error: 004C19ED01000000:error:0A000438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1590:SSL alert number 80
  ] {
    library: 'SSL routines',
    reason: 'tlsv1 alert internal error',
    code: 'ERR_SSL_TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR'
  }
}

Node.js v20.15.1

I have tried passing it to chatGPT, it has suggested me to update everything, download some packages, etc., but nothing worked.

So seems to be something SSL related. Search for the error ERR_SSL_TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR alert number 80 On the first look could be something ssl version related. The Error Error.captureStackTrace(err, this); is just the internal call to get the stacktrace
